# set <li> value id to <input> value but show the li text in input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, laravel

```js
$(document).on('click', 'li', function() {
  $('#operator_name').val($(this).text());
  let y = $(this).val();
  $('#operator_name').attr('data-id', y);
  $('#operator_list').fadeOut();
  alert(y)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="operator_name" name="operator_name" value=" ">
<div class="dropdown show " id="operator_list"></div>
```

this is the blade

```
public function fetch(Request $request) {
  if ($request->get('query')) {
      $query = $request->get('query');
      $data = DB::table('operators')
          // ->where('firstname', 'Like', '%{$query}%')
          ->where('firstname', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
          ->orWhere('middlename', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
          ->orWhere('surname', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
          ->get();
      $output = '<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="display:block;">';
       foreach ($data as $row) {
          $output .= '<li class="dropdown-item" value=' . $row->id . '>'. $row->surname.', '.$row->firstname.'</li>';
      }
      $output .= '</ul>';
      echo $output;
  }
}
```

this is the controller.

I managed to alert the li id while show the li text in input tag yet its the input text that will be saved in database i would like to save the li id at the same time show the li text in input tag, how to do it?

Comment: Can you please elaborate with an example (current behavior vs needed behavior)?

Comment: can you please change the blade with a simple html code example

Comment: i want to save the operator id but show the operator name

<option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->surname }}, {{ $user->firstname }}</option>

something like this, example only